# Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project using node in the backend and react in the frontend. Currently, I'm trying to integrate stripe into this project, but I'm getting an error stating:

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string.
```

in regards to this line of my code

```
const {error: stripeError, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret
```

I've been following the stripe tutorials on how to integrate their system, so I'm unsure of why I would be running into this issue. I'm also getting a `POST 404 http://localhost:3000/create-payment-intent (Not Found)` error. Could my `Uncaught (in promise)...`  error be causing this? Or is this a separate issue? I would really appreciate any help or advice on what could be causing this problem. Thank you!

PlaceOrderScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector, createSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {createOrder} from '../actions/orderActions';
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import {CardElement, useStripe, useElements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {paymentInfo} from '../actions/paymentActions';


export default function PlaceOrderScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const userId = userInfo._id;

 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

//test publishable API key.
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_51L6jyUDyOLU8ecQH9S20EgR9oeO34XL8401HbPjHKnrjHlstAfZwaJA6H1YtcfBVNCl1XaYFHWnfj75OYKlhc5ON00AULUvKnD");
const elements = useElements();
const stripe = useStripe();


const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!stripe || !elements) {
     console.log('Stripe.js has not yet loaded.')
      return;
    }

    
    const paymentMethodType = 'card';
    const currency = 'usd';
    const {error: backendError, clientSecret} = dispatch(paymentInfo({paymentMethodType, currency, userId}));
      /*'/create-payment-intent',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          paymentMethodType: 'card',
          currency: 'usd',
        }),
      } 
    ).then((r) => r.json()); */

  if (backendError) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('Client secret returned')
  const {error: stripeError, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret,
    {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
          name: 'Jane Smith',
        },
      },
    }
  );

  if (stripeError) {
    // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
    console.log('stripeError')
    return;
  }
  console.log(`Payment ${paymentIntent.status}: ${paymentIntent.id}`);
};

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-2">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div className="card card-body">
                <h2>Payment</h2>
                <div>
                   <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <>
                     <h1>Card</h1>
                      <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                       <label htmlFor="card">Card</label>
                       <CardElement id="card" />
                       <button type="submit">Pay</button>
                      </form>
                     </>
                    </Elements>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

paymentActions.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
    PAYMENT_REQUEST,
    PAYMENT_SUCCESS,
    PAYMENT_FAIL,
} from '../constants/paymentConstants';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants/app.constants';

export const paymentInfo = (paymentMethodType, currency, userId) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: PAYMENT_REQUEST, payload: {paymentMethodType, currency} });
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post( '/create-payment-intent', {
        paymentMethodType,
        currency,
        userId,
      });
      dispatch({ type: PAYMENT_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PAYMENT_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

paymentReducer.js

```
import {
    PAYMENT_REQUEST,
    PAYMENT_SUCCESS,
    PAYMENT_FAIL,
  } from '../constants/paymentConstants';
  
  export const paymentInfoReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PAYMENT_REQUEST:
        return { ...state, loading: true };
      case PAYMENT_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
      case PAYMENT_FAIL:
        return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

I also have paymentConstants and store.js (not shown)

Backend

stripe.js

```
import express from 'express';
import stripe from 'stripe';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import User from './models/userModel.js';
import Order from './models/orderModel.js';
const stripeToken = process.env.STRIPE_TOKEN;
const stripeClient = stripe(stripeToken);

const stripeRouter = express.Router();

stripeRouter.get(
    '/config',
 expressAsyncHandler((req, res) => {
    res.send({
      publishableKey: 'pk_test_51L6jyUDyOLU8ecQH9S20EgR9oeO34XL8401HbPjHKnrjHlstAfZwaJA6H1YtcfBVNCl1XaYFHWnfj75OYKlhc5ON00AULUvKnD',
    });
  })); 
  
  stripeRouter.post(
      '/create-payment-intent', 
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const {paymentMethodType, currency} = req.body;
  
   
    /*if (paymentMethodOptions) {
      params.payment_method_options = paymentMethodOptions
    }
    */
try {
      const paymentIntent = await stripeClient.paymentIntents.create({
          amount: 1999,
          currency: 'usd',
          payment_method_types: [],
      });
      console.log(paymentIntents)
      res.json({clientSecret:paymentIntent.client_secret})

      // Send publishable key and PaymentIntent details to client
     /* res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        nextAction: paymentIntent.next_action,
      });*/

    } catch (e) {
       res.status(400).json({
        error: {
          message: e.message,
        },
      });
    }
  }));
 
  export default stripeRouter;
```

Comment: The `/create-payment-intent` endpoint in your Express app is likely throwing an error, which you're not handling/catching correctly. Thus `client_secret` is not returned (and why Stripe.js is complaining).

Comment: You should wrap a try/catch block around your `handleSubmit` function that fires the API request to your Express app to create the Payment Intent. That `catch` block will correctly log the actual error from your API.

Comment: @JonathanSteele don't I have that in my ```paymentActions.js```? If I need that in my ```PlaceOrderScreen.js``` I tried adding it: ```const handleSubmit = async (e) => {e.preventDefault(); ...  try {const {error: backendError, clientSecret} = dispatch(paymentInfo({paymentMethodType, currency, userId}));... }  catch (submitError) { console.log(submitError) }```, which pretty much gave me the same error: ```IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string.```

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is in `handleSubmit` function in your `PlaceOrderScreen.js` component. You're destructuring a `clientSecret` parameter from your `PAYMENT_SUCCESS` dispatch action, yet that's not a returned parameter.